# Pychef api for getting info for a single node

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I'm trying to create an API that gets all the information for a single node from a chef server.

```
def get_nodeInfo(self, name):
```

the above is the methods head, so I pass the node name here. I have tried a lot of different methods found on internet but I keep getting "ChefServerNotFound: object not found" error. Does anyone have any advice for me on this.

```
result_set = chef.Search('node', q="name:test*")
for result in result_set:
  node = chef.Node(result["name"])
  print node
```

I used the above code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, please don't comment on old non-bugs to try and get attention. It pisses off maintainers and is not productive. Second, you don't need to use `search` at all to get a single node's data, just do `Node(name)` it will load.

Comment: sorry @coderanger I'm not trying to get attention, I am just asking for help. Because i have tried the Node(name) but when i try and get the run list it returns empty parameters .